# Is it acceptable to use a relative gradient because of convergence failure in LMER/GLMER?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, convergence, gradient

My research suggests that when an LMER/GLMER fails to converge due to a too-large deviance gradient...

e.g., `Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00297196 (tol = 0.001, component 1)`

1. [You should be worried](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110004/how-scared-should-we-be-about-convergence-warnings-in-lme4).
2. Everything possible should be done to examine the data for problems and question your assumptions (i.e., get to the root of the problem), as outlined [here](https://rpubs.com/bbolker/lme4trouble1).
3. As somewhat of a last resort, [you can check the relative gradient](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/120), which has been updated [here](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/269) (since the changelog entry linked above) to include the Choleski Factorization  e.g.,
   `relgrad <- with(model@optinfo$derivs,solve(chol(Hessian),gradient))
    max(abs(relgrad))`

Assuming you have done a lot of work at step 2, switching to a relative gradient to solve this problem still seems post-hoc if it is motivated by convergence failure under the `max|grad|` framework.

I'm looking for any advice or citations you can provide that describe the conditions that could a priori motivate the calculation and use of a relative gradient as above.

With some more digging, I found that the proposal to include a relative gradient as above was not incorporated into `lme4` and instead a help page `?convergence` was included that suggests to use many optimizers and compare the result, which is great, but it doesn't address my main question:

**Are there circumstances where it is acceptable to calculate the relative gradient as above, or, is this approach outdated/ill-advised?**

**Second, (and if the relative gradient is useful) when the relative gradient and the `lme4` stock `max|grad|` results diverge, what clues might this provide to resolve the issue on the data side?**