# What is a case where including random correlation parameters decreases the error on the fixed effects?

Tags: r, correlation, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

I'm wondering about the effect of true correlations among random effects on the standard error of my fixed effects in `lme4::lmer` models in R.

My assumption is that if there are true correlations--as indicated by a significant improvement in model fit when the correlation parameters are added to the model--then the inclusion of these parameters should improve the precision of the estimates somewhere else in the model. In particular, I would expect the standard error of the fixed effects to be smaller in the model in which the correlation parameters are contributing to the model fit.

However, a number of people have pointed out that the inclusion of correlation parameters do not improve the precision of the estimates of fixed effects even when they "improve" model fits:

1. [In a multi-level model, what are the practical implications of estimating versus not-estimating random effect correlation parameters?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49832/in-a-multi-level-model-what-are-the-practical-implications-of-estimating-versus)
2. I've conducted simulations of my own to the same end and presented them at a recent R user group meeting (Part 3: http://github.com/pedmiston/visualizing-lmer)
3. Shravan Vasishth has a few blog posts on a similar question, e.g., http://vasishth-statistics.blogspot.com/2014/11/should-we-fit-maximal-linear-mixed.html

I'm going to push the dialog even farther and challenge someone to demonstrate a situation in which including random effect correlation parameters does anything other than add complexity to the model.

My ignorance might be due to an over-interpretation of fixed effects as the best indicator of "average behavior", so I am interested to see the conditions under which random correlation parameters are useful to people who use these models to make inferences (as opposed to simply observing a correlation in the sample).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What if it makes the type I error rate for fixed effect parameters closer to the nominal value?

Comment: This is ham handed, but do you mean that random effects can never help you find an effect, all they do is prevent you (every once in a while, under conditions I don't yet know how to predict) from getting too excited?