# Generalized Linear Mixed Effects Logistic Regression with Repeated Measures

Tags: generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

I have an experiment where subjects reported multiple results (binary) in two treatments.  I have compared each subject separately to see if the treatment had an effect on a given subject, but would also like to compare the data as a whole.  I have gone with a Generalized Linear Mixed Effects Model (I have never done this type of analysis before).

I'm using the lme4 package in R and the glmer function, and I want to see the effect the treatment has on the results, so I have done the following:

```
model <- glmer(Response ~ Treatment + (Treatment|Subject), data=data, family=binomial(link=logit))
```

So the model puts the treatment as the fixed effect and takes into account the difference in the treatment for each subject as the random effect.  I am then looking at the significance of the treatment in the model.  Does that make sense or am I off my rocker?

Model output:

```
Fixed Effects:

                   Estimate   Std. Error   z value    PR(>|z|)
(Intercept)       -1.5066     0.2466       -6.109     1e-09 ***
Treatment         -0.6620     0.2803       -2.362     0.0182*

Random Effects:

                   Groups   Name        Variance   Std.Dev.  Corr
                   Subject  (Intercept) 0.4085     0.6391    
                            Treatment   0.002103   0.04585   -1.00
```

Thanks!

Comment: Makes sense to me.  I may possible worry about overfitting by including treatment as a random effect in addition to the fixed effect.  Does the fixed effect estimate significantly change if you remove it as a random effect?  Also that corr estimate of -1 seems odd.

Comment: Is the difference in treatment amongst participants really random or is it just that you are randomising them? If the latter then I don't think you need to make treatment a random effect, as the `Subject` variable takes care or that. Try making another model with `(1|Subject)` as the random effect. Then perform a likelihood ratio test (`anova(model1, model2)`). If the model without the trestment random effect is the same of superior then use that. Also if this is a repeated measures design you should probably account for those repeats in the fixed effects part of the model somewhere.

Comment: I think your model is overparameterized as @llewmills mentions.  See here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/323273/what-to-do-with-random-effects-correlation-that-equals-1-or-1.  If the order of treatments were randomized then include that order term as a fixed effect.

Comment: I removed the treatment in the random effect i.e. now it's (1|Subject) and it was pretty much the same the LRT came back with 0.98 so not seeing a difference there.  I thought since each subject was in both treatments I'd have to include the connection of both in the random effects. @llewmills how would you suggesting incorporating the repeated measures into the fixed effects?

Comment: @Glen thanks.  The order of treatments was randomized, some did treatment 1 first and some did treatment 2 first.  I did a bit of analysis on the side to see if it was having an effect and it didn't appear so.  Would you suggest something like Treatment*Position, where position is just an indicator of which treatment they did first?

Comment: Oh i see so it sounds like `treatment' already is the repeated measures fsctor (it has multiple levels i gather, and a single subject can be observed at some or all of those levels?). If so I think your model might be good to go

Comment: Yes I would suggest adding treatment*position.

Comment: @llewmills sorry I should be more clear, hard to explain all the components without writing a novel...Each subject does both treatments and within each treatment they have to answer 25 questions where the response is 0/1.  The treatment order is randomized, some did treatment 1 first and some did treatment 2 first.  The order of the questions are randomized between each treatment...i.e. "question 37" appears half of the time in treatment 1 and half of the time in treatment 2...and within each treatment...i.e. "question 37"'s placement was random within each treatment.

Comment: Ah. This is much more complex. I think  question within treatment might be a random effect.

Comment: @llewmills Hmm this is getting tricky. Because each group of questions within each Treatment for each Subject is different.  I certainly need the random effect of the Subject but then I also need the question number (QN).  So for the random effects something like (1|Subject) + (Subject|Treatment:QN).  The (1|Subject) should cover any random effects of the subjects alone.  While (Subject|Treatment:QN) is the random effects of the subjects which share on combinations of Treatment and Question number.

Comment: Yes it sounds like it. This is why I asked about your sample size. It may be you have too many random effects to achieve convergence. I'm sorry to do this to you but I can *highly* recommend Pinhiero and Bates' book *Mixed Effects Models in S and S-Plus*. Chapter 1 walks through some common repeated measures designs, with example code. I'm sure it will help you a lot.

Comment: ...and all the examples work in R

Comment: Perhaps `(1|Subject) + (1|QN/Treatment)`? Random effects such as these can be fiendishly confusing. There are so many ways to model them.

Comment: @llewmills thanks for the reference, I will definitely check it out.  The model converged easily with what you suggested.  I'll do a bit more reading before I choose a final model...but for now it's... Treatment*TreatmentPosition + (1|Subject) + (1|QN/Treatment).  The model saw the treatment for the Treatment fixed effect significant, while the TreatmentPosition and combination of Treatment and Treatment position were insignificant.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: That's great news @DanE, congrats! That's what you hypothesised I hope. Perhaps you could up-vote some of my comments? I need the rep :)