# Multilevel model with perfectly correlated intercept and slope

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, covariance-matrix

### Setup

Take a simple *mixed model* with *random intercepts* and *random slopes*. I would like to know how the *R* package *nlme* can be forced to assume perfectly correlated random intercepts and slopes.

The following code can generate data for the four model types listed below.

```
library(data.table)
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)
library(nlme)

make.data <- function(n_id, n_x, var_intercept, var_slope, 
  cor_intercept_slope, noise) {
  id <- seq(n_id)
  x <- seq(0, n_x)
  mu <- c(0, 0)
  cov_intercept_slope <- cor_intercept_slope * sqrt(var_slope 
    * var_intercept)
  sigma <- matrix(c(var_intercept, cov_intercept_slope, 
                   cov_intercept_slope, var_slope), 2, 2)
  data <- CJ(id = id, x = x)
  data[, y_line := apply(mvrnorm(1, mu, sigma) * rbind(rep(1, 
        n_x + 1), x), 2, sum), by = id]
  data[, y_points := y_line + rnorm(.N, 0, noise)]
  return(data)
}

make.plot <- function(data) {
  ggplot(data = data[id <= 7 & x <= 15]) +
    geom_line(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y_line, col = 
        factor(id))) +
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y_points, col = 
          factor(id))) +
    ylim(-4, 4)
}
```

### Random intercept only

In case of a mixed model with *only* a random intercept, the data may look something like the graph below.

```
data_intercept <- make.data(10^3, 10^2, 1.9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1)
make.plot(data_intercept)
```

[image: Random intercept graph]

To fit this data using *nlme*, the following *formula* can be used. There are *two* unknowns to be estimated; the size of the random noise and the variance of the random intercepts. These agree with the inputted values.

```
fit_intercept <- lme(y_points ~ 0, data_intercept, 
         list(id = ~ 1))
VarCorr(fit_intercept)["Residual", "StdDev"] # approx 0.1
VarCorr(fit_intercept)["(Intercept)", "Variance"] 
                                         # approx 1.9
```

### Random slope only

In case of a mixed model with *only* a random slope, the data may look something like the graph below.

```
data_slope <- make.data(10^3, 10^2, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.1)
make.plot(data_slope)
```

[image: Random slope graph]

To fit this data using *nlme*, the following *formula* can be used. There are *two* unknowns to be estimated; the size of the random noise and the variance of the random slopes. These agree with the inputted values.

```
fit_slope <- lme(y_points ~ 0, data_slope, list(id = ~ 0 + 
                  x))
VarCorr(fit_slope)["Residual", "StdDev"] # approx 0.1
VarCorr(fit_slope)["x", "Variance"] # approx 0.1
```

### Random intercept and slope

In case of a mixed model with *both* a random intercept and a random slope, the data may look something like the graph below.

```
data_intercept_slope_free <- make.data(10^3, 10^2, 0.8, 0.05, 
                                0.4, 0.1)
make.plot(data_intercept_slope_free)
```

[image: Random intercept and slope graph]

To fit this data using *nlme*, the following *formula* can be used. There are *four* unknowns to be estimated; the size of the random noise, the variance of the random intercepts, the variance of the random slopes and, finally, the correlation between intercept and slope. These agree with the inputted values.

```
fit_intercept_slope_free <- lme(y_points ~ 0, 
     data_intercept_slope_free, list(id = ~ 1 + x))
VarCorr(fit_intercept_slope_free)["Residual", "StdDev"] 
            # approx 0.1
VarCorr(fit_intercept_slope_free)["(Intercept)", "Variance"] 
            # approx 0.8
VarCorr(fit_intercept_slope_free)["x", "Variance"] 
            # approx 0.05
VarCorr(fit_intercept_slope_free)["x", "Corr"] # approx 0.4
```

### Random perfectly correlated intercept and slope

However, one can imagine another model which is nested inside the last model but only has *three* unknowns to be estimated. If the random intercept and the random slope are *perfectly correlated*, the data may look something like the graph below.

```
data_intercept_slope_fixed <- make.data(10^3, 10^2, 0.6, 
   0.05, 1.0, 0.1)
make.plot(data_intercept_slope_fixed)
```

[image: Random perfectly correlated intercept and slope graph]

Theoretically, this is equivalent to the random slopes model, but with the $x$-axis horizontally translated by some value such that the slopes do not cross at $x=0$ but at some other $x=a$. I can imagine this occurring frequently in practice.

### Question

- What syntax for the *nlme* formula can *force* the correlation to be equal to 1? Something like `random = list(id = pdSymm(~ 1 + x, cor = 1))`.
- Or alternatively, how can I estimate the horizontal translation in $x$? Something like `random = list(id = ~ I(x + a))`.

I realise that obtaining a *singular fit* is generally a [sign](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/323273/what-to-do-with-random-effects-correlation-that-equals-1-or-1) of [overfitting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/378939/dealing-with-singular-fit-in-mixed-models/379068). In my case, I have theoretical grounds to assume this perfect correlation and I am merely interested in obtaining the correct syntax within *nlme* (if this is even [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399127/lme4-how-to-specify-2-correlations-with-random-intercept-without-adding-correl/35401176)).

Comment: I think probably the easiest way to do something like this would be to switch to a Bayesian setup where you put an extremely informative prior on the slope-intercept covariance. Also see this CV thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/323273/what-to-do-with-random-effects-correlation-that-equals-1-or-1